# Переодическии падает сервер на ubuntu

Tags: linux, apache, nginx

Стоит ubuntu 14, панель vesta, недавно я ставил letsencrypt сертификаты, до этого вроде он так не падал.
В логах апача следующие ошибки:

```
[Sun Apr 17 04:05:22.536393 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 30605] AH02292: Init: Name-based SSL virtual hosts only work for clients with TLS server name indication support (RFC 4366)
[Sun Apr 17 04:05:22.536465 2016] [suexec:notice] [pid 30605] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/lib/apache2/suexec)
[Sun Apr 17 04:05:29.932891 2016] [:notice] [pid 30606] mod_ruid2/0.9.8 enabled
[Sun Apr 17 04:05:29.934234 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 30606] AH02292: Init: Name-based SSL virtual hosts only work for clients with TLS server name indication support (RFC 4366)
[Sun Apr 17 04:05:30.237438 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 30606] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14 OpenSSL/1.0.1f configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Apr 17 04:05:30.237479 2016] [core:notice] [pid 30606] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

Пример логов nginx'a:

```
2016/02/17 15:19:40 [alert] 1133#0: worker process 1136 exited on signal 9
2016/04/09 13:38:22 [emerg] 23131#0: bind() to 0.0.0.0:8083 failed (98: Address already in use)
2016/04/09 13:38:22 [emerg] 23131#0: bind() to 0.0.0.0:8083 failed (98: Address already in use)
2016/04/09 13:38:22 [emerg] 23131#0: bind() to 0.0.0.0:8083 failed (98: Address already in use)
2016/04/09 13:38:22 [emerg] 23131#0: bind() to 0.0.0.0:8083 failed (98: Address already in use)
2016/04/09 13:38:22 [emerg] 23131#0: bind() to 0.0.0.0:8083 failed (98: Address already in use)
2016/04/09 13:38:22 [emerg] 23131#0: still could not bind()
2016/04/11 02:11:22 [alert] 1100#0: worker process 1103 exited on signal 9
```

Скорее всего дело в апаче я думаю, гуглил по интернету но по моей ошибки мало инфы, как я понял дело в ssl? Как можно исправить эти ошибки?

Comment: В ваших логах апача ни строчки о том почему бы он мог упасть. А nginx говорит, что порт 8083 занят. Скорее всего у вас какое то другое приложение использует этот порт.

Comment: А которые он пишет предупреждения по поводу ssl не могут к этому приводить? Больше в логах там нет ничего, получается проблема с портами?

Comment: Ну там предупреждения, что не все клиенты поймут  сертификаты по именам доменов. А nginx тупо не может занять порт и не запускается вообще.

Comment: Интересно, но по датам эти логи апача совпадают, с датами когда сервер лежал, где еще можно посмотреть что не так, логи что были я привел, больше и не знаю где смотреть.